# Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#

Hai,

In my code while executing a function i got regularly the exception error as "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

The function exceuting is as follows

```
private void PageHeaderSetting(Graphics g)
        {
            try
            {
                DataTable dtPageHeader=new DataTable() ;
                dtPageHeader = ds.Tables["Page Header"];
                if (dtPageHeader.Rows.Count != 0)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow dr in dtPageHeader.Rows)
                    {
                        if (dr.ItemArray[0].ToString() != "")
                            PageHeaderText = dr.ItemArray[0].ToString();
                        else
                            PageHeaderText = "";
                        if (dr.ItemArray[1].ToString() != "")
                            PageHeaderFont = (Font)dr.ItemArray[1];
                        else
                            PageHeaderFont = new Font("Tahoma", 18, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point);
                        if (dr.ItemArray[2].ToString() != "")
                            PageHeaderFormat = AlignmentSetting(dr.ItemArray[2].ToString());
                        else
                            PageHeaderFormat = AlignmentSetting(Convert.ToString(Alignment.Left));
                        if (dr.ItemArray[3].ToString() != "")
                            PageHeaderColor = (System.Drawing.Color)dr.ItemArray[3];
                        else
                            PageHeaderColor = Color.Black;

                        PageFooterText = Word_Wrap(PageHeaderText, PageHeaderFont, g, 0);
                        PageHeader(g);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

How can i solve this.Can anybody help me?

From the second line i got the exception error
means after declaring the datatable and putting the ds.Tables in it from there erroe occurs

Comment: What line is the exception being thrown from?

Comment: Please post, Which line?

Comment: It would help if you told us where (on what line) the error occurred.
Also you have variables (like "ds") that appear "out of the blue".

Comment: On which line was the exception thrown? Please tell us.

Comment: Minor remark: you don't need the "new DataTable()" as you overwrite that in the next line. Just a DataTable dtPageHeader=ds.Tables["Page Header"]; is enough.

Answer (score 6):

This exception means you're trying to call a method on a null object. The exception should have given you a stack trace with the line number it was thrown at; this'll help you pin it down a bit. You could also try debugging it in visual studio and see where the exception is thrown & see what is null.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using ToString() to check if you have a value in the ItemArray you should check the actual value. Check for ItemArray[0] == null and ItemArray[0] == DBNull.Value.

Edit:
From your comment it seems that there may not be any data table named "Page Header" in your data set.

Try to add a null check to your DataTable object after the line `dtPageHeader = ds.Tables["Page Header"];`

Something like this:

```
if (dtPageHeader == null) 
{ 
   // There is no table named Page Header
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the line number in the exception.

Your code has numerous chained calls, which is a common source of this exception. If either of these chained properties returns null, the "next" call in the chain will fail with a NullReferenceException.

Answer (score 0):

One of this could be true:

- ds is null
- A Value on a columun in dtPageHeader is null